# How can i read data from a json file saved in the sdcard?

Tags: java, android

I would like to know using Android Studio how to load & read a json file saved in the sdcard?
The json file contains simple json objects. Also after getting the data how can i parse it & set it as pojo.

Json example:
{
"name":"Abcd",
"id":"xyz"
}

Thanks.

Comment: Json file or other file, loading/reading is all the same. And parsing json is like always. Nothing different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading file:

```
InputStream iStream = new FileInputStream("filename.json"); 
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
String line; 
String content = "";
while((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) { 
    content += line;
}
```

the easiest way to convert to POJO is to use one of the popular libraries (Gson, Jackson, etc). Using Gson:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
gson.fromJson(content, Pojo.class);
```